# sort string array in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have two string arrays in `ar1` and `ar2`, and I am reading the input from file and storing in arrays , `ar1` contains

```
Cat
Lam
Orange
Kam
Ramveer
None
Tue
Apple
```

ar2 contains

```
Dog
elephant
Kam
Monday
Parrot
Queen
Ramveer
Tuesday
Xmas
```

I am trying to sort the arrays in alphabetical order, and i am using `Array.sort()` , but getting the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:232)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:176)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
at CompareArrays.pr1(CompareArrays.java:51)
at CompareArrays.main(CompareArrays.java:86)
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

**Code**

```
File file1= new File("C:\\Users\\Ramveer\\Desktop\\updates\\f1.txt");
File file2=new File("C:\\Users\\Ramveer\\Desktop\\updates\\f2.txt");
Scanner sc1=new Scanner(file1);
Scanner sc2=new Scanner(file2);
while(sc1.hasNextLine()){
ar1[c1]=sc1.nextLine();
c1++;
}

while(sc2.hasNextLine()){
ar2[c2]=sc2.nextLine();
c2++;
 }
  Arrays.sort(ar1);
  for(int k=0;k<c1;k++){
      System.out.println(ar1[k]);}

  }
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your array probably contains a null item. Typically, if you declare an array of size 10 (for example) but only put 9 strings in it, the 10th item will be null.

Comment: Why is `c1` not initialized?..

Comment: Did you try debugging? That should sort the problem out quickly.

Comment: He might have left that part out though.

Comment: why don't you just print content of arrays and check where the problem is? First debug yourself.

Comment: @all i have initialize c1=0, when i printing the arrays they will print the output as shown in my question, the problem is it is not printing the sorted output of array , as i mention in question briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Arraylist as then you dont have to estimate the size of your array as the ArrayList grows dynamically as you add more strings, your code would go something like this

```
File file1= new File("C:\\Users\\Ramveer\\Desktop\\updates\\f1.txt");
File file2=new File("C:\\Users\\Ramveer\\Desktop\\updates\\f2.txt");
Scanner sc1=new Scanner(file1);
Scanner sc2=new Scanner(file2);
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>()
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>()

while(sc1.hasNextLine())
   list1.add(sc1.nextLine().toLowerCase());  //edited -- bad approach but would work if case not important


while(sc2.hasNextLine()){
   list2.add(sc2.nextLine().toLowerCase());  //edited -- bad approach but would work if case not important

Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);
for(String s: list1)
   System.out.println(s);
```

Or you could do this to implement a case insensitive sort, which would be better then altering the string as you add it to array

```
Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<Object>() 
{
     @Override
     public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
     {
         String s1 = (String) o1;
         String s2 = (String) o2;
         return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
}
```

Then repeat for list2. But an even better way would be to write a new comparator method as such

```
public class SortIgnoreCase implements Comparator<Object> {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String s1 = (String) o1;
        String s2 = (String) o2;
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
}
```

then call  `Collections.sort(list1, new SortIgnoreCase());` which is a cleaner way to write the code to sort multiple lists

Comment: Thanks @java Devil , approach work file but it gives the result Dog
   Kam
   Monday
   Parrot
   Queen
   Ramveer
   Tuesday
   Xmas
   elephant   but in correct result elephant should be after Dog , why is this happening.

Comment: also when we use string.compareto method it will shows that kam is greater than elephant.

Comment: so i think it is not sorting while ignoring the case(not case sensitive), how can i do it without caring about capital and small letters(not case sensitive)

Comment: Thats correct that it is sorting case sensitive as the character value of lower case letters is higher than uppercase letters. If you want to ignore case when comparing strings you can use the `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` methods which are part of the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). But this will convert the whole string to that case so if you do `s.toUpperCase.equals("UPPER")` for `s="upper"` this will return true. I've edited above to add lowercase into list so sort will be correct.

Comment: There is also the methods `equalsIgnoreCase()` and `compareToIgnoreCase()` for `Strings` also

Comment: @RSverma Edited using multiple approaches for sorting with case insenstivity, Hope one works out.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using arrays, you must predict the number of entries in advance. It seems like your prediction is off, so some array elements stay `null`.

Please consider using [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a raw array. Sorting is done with `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Indeed! I think you should use ArrayList over Array when you can.

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are too big for the data, you'll have the default value of `null` in the unused elements; these `null` values will cause your exception.

Before loading and sorting your arrays, put blanks in all elements:

```
Arrays.fill(a1, "");
Arrays.fill(a2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use arrays then use this for reading:

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
    while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(sc1.nextLine());
    }
    String[] ar1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
```

If you can use List collection instead then:

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
    while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(sc1.nextLine());
    }
    Collections.sort(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Array don't have null values `Arrays.sort()`works properly.

So it is better to use `List` to avoid that kind of a scenario.

Then you can convert your arrays to `ArrayList` and use `Collections.sort()` to sort them.

```
    String[] str1 = {"Cat","Lam","Orange","Kam","Ramveer","None","Tue","Apple"};
    String[] str2 = {"Dog","Elephant","Kam","Monday","Parrot","Queen","Ramveer","Tuesday","Xmas"};
    List<String> lst1=Arrays.asList(str1);
    List<String> lst2=Arrays.asList(str2);
    Collections.sort(lst1);
    Collections.sort(lst2);
    System.out.println(lst1+"\n"+lst2);
```

Comment: Using `List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(str1);` would look neater.